# In a dual boot setup, how do I move Windows 10 partition to new drive?

Tags: partitioning, multi-boot

My lsblk output looks like this

```
nvme0n1     259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk 
├─nvme0n1p1 259:1    0   100M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p2 259:2    0    16M  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p3 259:3    0   390G  0 part 
├─nvme0n1p4 259:4    0   513M  0 part 
└─nvme0n1p5 259:5    0 540.9G  0 part /
```

I have a new SATA SSD so I'd like to move my Windows installation to this new drive.

If I create a partition table that mimics the first 3 partitions here, can I `dd` the partitions into them like this?

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p1 of=/dev/sda1 bs=4M
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p2 of=/dev/sda2 bs=4M
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1p3 of=/dev/sda3 bs=4M
```

Answer (score -2):

Presuming that the partitions on the target disk are created and are exactly the same size as the source and are flagged properly, you should be able to use the `dd` command to clone the partitions to the other drive. But you will have to install/reinstall the MBR on the target drive and/or regenerate GRUB entries on the source drive (assuming it remains in use).

However, I would suggest avoiding manual cloning because there is a very high chance that you will end up with an unbootable system. I recommend using specialized tools that automate the steps described above and have a much higher success rate than manual cloning. One such tool is [CloneZilla](https://clonezilla.org/), a live-boot distribution designed specifically for your use case. You can use the disk-to-disk mode and select `part_to_local_part`. From the advanced menu, select "Copy MBR." Detailed steps are described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/709894/407793).

After you have verified that the cloning was successful, you should be able to resize the `/dev/sda3` partition to use all available space using tools like [GParted](https://gparted.org/).

Comment: It seems ChatGPT needs to learn about UEFI and, ironically, GPT.

Comment: @ChanganAuto lol, great catch. guess I can try Clonezilla though.